# Parsing the arrow type with FParsec

Tags: f#, parsec, fparsec

I'm trying to parse the arrow type with FParsec.
That is, this:

```
Int -> Int -> Int -> Float -> Char
```

For example.

I tried with this code, but it only works for one type of arrow (`Int -> Int`) and no more. I also want to avoid parentheses, because I already have a tuple type that uses them, and I don't want it to be too heavy in terms of syntax either.

```
let ws = pspaces >>. many pspaces |>> (fun _ -> ())

let str_ws s = pstring s .>> ws

type Type = ArrowType of Type * Type

let arrowtype' =
    pipe2
        (ws >>. ty')
        (ws >>. str_ws "->" >>. ws >>. ty')
        (fun t1 t2 -> ArrowType(t1, t2))

let arrowtype =
    pipe2
        (ws >>. ty' <|> arrowtype')
        (ws >>. str_ws "->" >>. ws >>. ty' <|> arrowtype')
        (fun t1 t2 -> ArrowType(t1, t2)) <?> "arrow type"
```

`ty'` is just another types, like tuple or identifier.

Do you have a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before I get into the arrow syntax, I want to comment on your `ws` parser. Using `|>> (fun _ -> ())` is a little inefficient since FParsec has to construct a result object then immediately throw it away. The built-in [`spaces`](http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/reference/charparsers.html#members.spaces) and [`spaces1`](http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/reference/charparsers.html#members.spaces1) parsers are probably better for your needs, since they don't need to construct a result object.

Now as for the issue you're struggling with, it looks to me like you want to consider the arrow parser slightly differently. What about treating it as a series of types separated by `->`, and using the [`sepBy`](http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/reference/primitives.html#members.sepBy) family of parser combinators? Something like this:

```
let arrow = spaces1 >>. pstring "->" .>> spaces1
let arrowlist = sepBy1 ty' arrow
let arrowtype = arrowlist |>> (fun types ->
    types |> List.reduce (fun ty1 ty2 -> ArrowType(ty1, ty2))
```

Note that the `arrowlist` parser would *also* match against just plain `Int`, because the definition of `sepBy1` is not "there must be at least one list separator", but rather "there must be at least one item in the list". So to distinguish between a type of `Int` and an arrow type, you'd want to do something like:

```
let typeAlone = ty' .>> notFollowedBy arrow
let typeOrArrow = attempt typeAlone <|> arrowtype
```

The use of `attempt` is necessary here so that the characters consumed by `ty'` will be backtracked if an arrow was present.

There's a complicating factor I haven't addressed at all since you mentioned not wanting parentheses. But if you decide that you want to be able to have arrow types *of arrow types* (that is, functions that take functions as input), you'd want to parse types like `(Int -> Int) -> (Int -> Float) -> Char`. This would complicate the use of `sepBy`, and I haven't addressed it at all. If you end up needing more complex parsing including parentheses, then it's possible you might want to use [`OperatorPrecedenceParser`](http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/reference/operatorprecedenceparser.html). But for your simple needs where parentheses aren't involved, `sepBy1` looks like your best bet.

Finally, I should give a **WARNING**: I haven't tested this at all, just typed this into the Stack Overflow box. The code example I gave you is not intended to be working as-is, but rather to give you an idea of how to proceed. If you need a working-as-is example, I'll be happy to try to give you one, but I don't have the time to do so right now.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I can see better how to proceed now, the use of a list of type seems to me easier to parse, and later to analyze.
I think I can handle this :)