# Parsing the signature of a function - Error with the arrow type - FParsec + indentation

Tags: f#, indentation, fparsec

I had already [asked a question about how to parse the arrow type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53655643/parsing-the-arrow-type-with-fparsec), this is not a duplicate, but rather an adaptation with the indentation based syntax.

Indeed, I would like to be able to analyze a syntax close to that of the ML family languages. I also introduced the syntax of the type signature of a function in Haskell, so this:

```
myFunction :: atype
```

My parser works very well for all kinds of signature types, except the arrow type when it is "alone":

```
foo :: a // ok
foo :: [a] // ok
foo :: (a, a) // ok
foo :: [a -> a] // ok
foo :: (a -> a, a) // ok
foo :: a -> a // error
```

Same for the creation of functions (to make it simple, I just expected a number as a value):

```
foo: a = 0 // ok
foo: [a] = 0 // ok
foo: (a, a) = 0 // ok
foo: [a -> a] = 0 // ok
foo: (a -> a, a) = 0 // ok
foo: a -> a = 0 // error
```

Without the indentation, all these cases work a priori.

I tried a module to parse the indentation other than the FParsec wiki, just to try and evaluate a little. [It comes from there](https://github.com/manio143/IndentFParsec), and here is the necessary and sufficient module code for the question:

```
module IndentParser =
  type Indentation = 
      | Fail
      | Any
      | Greater of Position 
      | Exact of Position 
      | AtLeast of Position 
      | StartIndent of Position
      with
        member this.Position = match this with
                                | Any | Fail -> None
                                | Greater p -> Some p
                                | Exact p -> Some p
                                | AtLeast p -> Some p
                                | StartIndent p -> Some p

  type IndentState<'T> = { Indent : Indentation; UserState : 'T }
  type CharStream<'T> = FParsec.CharStream<IndentState<'T>>
  type IndentParser<'T, 'UserState> = Parser<'T, IndentState<'UserState>>

  let indentState u = {Indent = Any; UserState = u}
  let runParser p u s = runParserOnString p (indentState u) "" s
  let runParserOnFile p u path = runParserOnFile p (indentState u) path System.Text.Encoding.UTF8

  let getIndentation : IndentParser<_,_> =
    fun stream -> match stream.UserState with
                  | {Indent = i} -> Reply i
  let getUserState : IndentParser<_,_> =
    fun stream -> match stream.UserState with
                  | {UserState = u} -> Reply u

  let putIndentation newi : IndentParser<unit, _> =
    fun stream ->
      stream.UserState <- {stream.UserState with Indent = newi}
      Reply(Unchecked.defaultof<unit>)

  let failf fmt = fail << sprintf fmt

  let acceptable i (pos : Position) =
    match i with
    | Any _ -> true
    | Fail -> false
    | Greater bp -> bp.Column < pos.Column
    | Exact ep -> ep.Column = pos.Column
    | AtLeast ap -> ap.Column <= pos.Column
    | StartIndent _ -> true

  let tokeniser p = parse {
    let! pos = getPosition
    let! i = getIndentation
    if acceptable i pos then return! p
    else return! failf "incorrect indentation at %A" pos
  }

  let indented<'a,'u> i (p : Parser<'a,_>) : IndentParser<_, 'u> = parse {
    do! putIndentation i
    do! spaces
    return! tokeniser p
  }

  /// Allows to check if the position of the parser currently being analyzed (`p`)
  /// is on the same line as the defined position (`pos`).
  let exact<'a,'u> pos p: IndentParser<'a, 'u> = indented (Exact pos) p
  /// Allows to check if the position of the parser currently being analyzed (`p`)
  /// is further away than the defined position (`pos`).
  let greater<'a,'u> pos p: IndentParser<'a, 'u> = indented (Greater pos) p
  /// Allows to check if the position of the parser currently being analyzed (`p`)
  /// is on the same OR line further than the defined position (`pos`).
  let atLeast<'a,'u> pos p: IndentParser<'a, 'u> = indented (AtLeast pos) p
  /// Simply check if the parser (`p`) exists, regardless of its position in the text to be analyzed.
  let any<'a,'u> pos p: IndentParser<'a, 'u> = indented Any p

  let newline<'u> : IndentParser<unit, 'u> = many (skipAnyOf " \t" <?> "whitespace") >>. newline |>> ignore

  let rec blockOf p = parse {
    do! spaces
    let! pos = getPosition    
    let! x = exact pos p
    let! xs = attempt (exact pos <| blockOf p) <|> preturn []
    return x::xs
  }
```

Now, here is the code I'm trying to fix for the problem I encountered:

```
module Parser =
    open IndentParser

    type Identifier = string

    type Type =
        | Typename of Identifier
        | Tuple of Type list
        | List of Type
        | Arrow of Type * Type
        | Infered

    type Expression =
        | Let of Identifier * Type * int
        | Signature of Identifier * Type

    type Program = Program of Expression list

// Utils -----------------------------------------------------------------

    let private ws = spaces

    /// All symbols granted for the "opws" parser
    let private allowedSymbols =
        ['!'; '@'; '#'; '$'; '%'; '+'; '&'; '*'; '('; ')'; '-'; '+'; '='; '?'; '/'; '>'; '<'; '|']

    /// Parse an operator and white spaces around it: `ws >>. p .>> ws`
    let inline private opws str =
        ws >>.
        (tokeniser (pstring str >>?
            (nextCharSatisfiesNot
                (isAnyOf (allowedSymbols @ ['"'; '''])) <?> str))) .>> ws

    let private identifier =
        (many1Satisfy2L isLetter
            (fun c -> isLetter c || isDigit c) "identifier")

// Types -----------------------------------------------------------------

    let rec typename = parse {
            let! name = ws >>. identifier
            return Type.Typename name
        }

    and tuple_type = parse {
            let! types = between (opws "(") (opws ")") (sepBy (ws >>. type') (opws ","))
            return Type.Tuple types
        }

    and list_type = parse {
            let! ty = between (opws "[") (opws "]") type'
            return Type.List ty
        }

    and arrow_type =
        chainr1 (typename <|> tuple_type <|> list_type) (opws "->" >>% fun t1 t2 -> Arrow(t1, t2))

    and type' =
        attempt arrow_type <|>
        attempt typename <|>
        attempt tuple_type <|>
        attempt list_type

// Expressions -----------------------------------------------------------------

    let rec private let' = parse {
            let! pos = getPosition
            let! id = exact pos identifier
            do! greater pos (opws ":")
            let! ty = greater pos type'
            do! greater pos (opws "=")
            let! value = greater pos pint32
            return Expression.Let(id, ty, value)
        }

    and private signature = parse {
            let! pos = getPosition
            let! id = exact pos identifier
            do! greater pos (opws "::")
            let! ty = greater pos type'
            return Expression.Signature(id, ty)
        }

    and private expression =
        attempt let'

    and private expressions = blockOf expression <?> "expressions"

    let private document = ws >>. expressions .>> ws .>> eof |>> Program

    let private testType = ws >>. type' .>> ws .>> eof

    let rec parse code =
        runParser document () code
        |> printfn "%A"

open Parser

parse @"

foo :: a -> a

"
```

Here is the error message obtained:

[image]

There is no reference to indentation in the error message, that's what troubles also, because if I implement an identical parser, except for indentation parsing, it works.

Could you put me on the right way?

**EDIT**

Here is the "fixed" code (the use of the function signature parser was missing + removal of unnecessary `attempt`):

```
open FParsec

// module IndentParser

module Parser =
    open IndentParser

    type Identifier = string

    type Type =
        | Typename of Identifier
        | Tuple of Type list
        | List of Type
        | Arrow of Type * Type
        | Infered

    type Expression =
        | Let of Identifier * Type * int
        | Signature of Identifier * Type

    type Program = Program of Expression list

// Utils -----------------------------------------------------------------

    let private ws = spaces

    /// All symbols granted for the "opws" parser
    let private allowedSymbols =
        ['!'; '@'; '#'; '$'; '%'; '+'; '&'; '*'; '('; ')'; '-'; '+'; '='; '?'; '/'; '>'; '<'; '|']

    /// Parse an operator and white spaces around it: `ws >>. p .>> ws`
    let inline private opws str =
        ws >>.
        (tokeniser (pstring str >>?
            (nextCharSatisfiesNot
                (isAnyOf (allowedSymbols @ ['"'; '''])) <?> str))) .>> ws

    let private identifier =
        (many1Satisfy2L isLetter
            (fun c -> isLetter c || isDigit c) "identifier")

// Types -----------------------------------------------------------------

    let rec typename = parse {
            let! name = ws >>. identifier
            return Type.Typename name
        }

    and tuple_type = parse {
            let! types = between (opws "(") (opws ")") (sepBy (ws >>. type') (opws ","))
            return Type.Tuple types
        }

    and list_type = parse {
            let! ty = between (opws "[") (opws "]") type'
            return Type.List ty
        }

    and arrow_type =
        chainr1 (typename <|> tuple_type <|> list_type) (opws "->" >>% fun t1 t2 -> Arrow(t1, t2))

    and type' =
        attempt arrow_type <|>
        typename <|>
        tuple_type <|>
        list_type

// Expressions -----------------------------------------------------------------

    let rec private let' = parse {
            let! pos = getPosition
            let! id = exact pos identifier
            do! greater pos (opws ":")
            let! ty = greater pos type'
            do! greater pos (opws "=")
            let! value = greater pos pint32
            return Expression.Let(id, ty, value)
        }

    and private signature = parse {
            let! pos = getPosition
            let! id = exact pos identifier
            do! greater pos (opws "::")
            let! ty = greater pos type'
            return Expression.Signature(id, ty)
        }

    and private expression =
        attempt let' <|>
        signature

    and private expressions = blockOf expression <?> "expressions"

    let private document = ws >>. expressions .>> ws .>> eof |>> Program

    let private testType = ws >>. type' .>> ws .>> eof

    let rec parse code =
        runParser document () code
        |> printfn "%A"

open Parser

System.Console.Clear()

parse @"

foo :: a -> a

"
```

So, here are the new error messages:

[image]
and
[image]

Comment: Solved it, I think. In `opws`, replace `ws >>.` with `ws >>?` so that if your operator isn't matched, `opws` fails without consuming input. This will probably solve all sorts of issues in your parser, not just this one. See my edited answer for the full details.

Comment: It worked wonderfully well :) FParsec decidedly contains a lot of great features. Thank you.

Comment: As a matter of fact, I think I'd recommend replacing `ws >>.` with `ws >>?` everywhere it appears: in `typename` and in `tuple_type`, for example. There is pretty much never a situation where you want `ws >>. some_meaningful_parser`; you always want to backtrack to before the whitespace if `some_meaningful_parser` fails, so that any `<|>` or `choice` combinators will be able to do the right thing. That means that `ws >>? some_meaningful_parser` is always what you want.

Comment: I'll take note of that, thank you. A quick question, is `.>>?` also worth inserting if you expect something after a certain parser? If we follow your advice in relation to `>>.` which becomes `>>?` ?

Comment: In general, yes. The rule of thumb is to think about where parsing should resume if some component fails. If you use `.>>` and the second component fails, then the whole parser will fail *after consuming input* and that will mean that you can't backtrack to try an alternative. And *sometimes that's what you want*, which is why I can't say that you always want to use `.>>?`. But often, if the second component fails, you want to backtrack all the way to the start, which means using `.>>?` in that scenario. Just think about where parsing should resume in each particular case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, your code is failing on the `::` signature because you haven't actually used your `signature` parser anywhere. You have defined `expression` as `attempt let'`, but I think you meant to write `attempt signature <|> attempt let'`. That is why your test is failing on the second colon of `::`, because it's matching the single colon of a `let'` and then not expecting the second colon.

Also, I think your chaining multiple `attempt` combinators together like `attempt a <|> attempt b <|> attempt c` is going to cause you problems somewhere, and that you should remove the final `attempt`, e.g., `attempt a <|> attempt b <|> c`. If you use `attempt` in all the possible choices, you'll end up with a parser that can succeed by parsing nothing, which is often *not* what you intended.

**Update:** I think I've found the cause and the solution.

**Summary:** In your `opws` parser, replace the line `ws >>.` with `ws >>?`.

**Explanation:** In all the `sepBy` variants (and `chainr1` is a `sepBy` variant), FParsec expects that the separator parser will either succeed, or will fail *without consuming input*. (If the separator fails after consuming input, FParsec considers the entire `sepBy`-family parser to have failed in its entirety.) But your `opws` parser will consume whitespace, then fail if it doesn't find a correct operator. So when your `arrow_type` parser parses the string `a -> a` *followed by a newline*, the arrow after the first `a` is correctly matched, then it sees the second `a`, and then it tries to find another arrow. Since what follows next is at least one whitespace character ([newlines count as whitespace](http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/reference/charparsers.html#members.spaces)), the `opws "->"` parser ends up consuming some input before it fails. (It fails because after that whitespace is the end of the file, not another `->` token). This makes the `chainr1` combinator fail, so `arrow_type` fails and your `a -> a` parser ends up being parsed as a single type `a`. (At which point the arrow is now unexpected).

By using `>>?` in your definition of `opws`, you ensure that if the second part of the parser fails, it will backtrack to before it matched any whitespace. That ensures that the separator parser will fail *without matching input* and without advancing the parse position in the character stream. Therefore, the `chainr1` parser succeeds after parsing `a -> a` and you get the expected results.

Comment: Indeed, when I transcribed my code into a minimal code, I forgot to use the `signature` parser (in my real code, I have more than 600 lines, I had to sort ^^)... But the problem still arises. I edited my question. Thanks for the advice on `attempt` otherwise, it's true that I use it too often. I hope you will be able to help me with this edit.